# Making a Static Div When it scrolls Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a div which scrolls vertically but not horizontally. Here`s the image that explains well about the process..

![enter image description here][1]

I want the Y-axis to remain static while it scroll in the right side. Here`s my HTML code

```
 <div id="i">
    <div class="column">
     <div id="y_axis"></div>
       <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="x_axis"></div>
     </div>
```

Div Chart is where the bars are there. Whenever I scroll right only the chart moves right and not the Y-axis.

CSS

```
 #chart {

        left: 40px;
        display: block;
float:right;
    }
    #y_axis {
        position:fixed;
        top: 14px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 40px;
        background-image: url('../img/avg_price.PNG');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center left;
float:right;


    }
    #x_axis {
        position: relative;
        left: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

Tried with Position relative which changes the position of the yaxis itself but not working. What should I do here?

Comment: use `overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: used it in the y-axis div and it creates a extra scroll button.. And the y-axis also scrolling when scroll right.. not working

Comment: Make a fiddle with css that contains a full path reference to the image you are using: jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user2146515 - Why did you submit that as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: BTW, that is not a normal browser window scroll.. Arrow mark Image which is on the right and left used for scrolling...

Answer (score 2):

I Assume your after something like this : **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2jPD/1/)**

I switched from a `background-image` to `img` tags in your markup. I've also modified your `width`'s to adjust for the overflow of the image and taken out the `chart` `div`:

```
<div id="i">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="y_axis"><img src="img/src/goes/here"/></div>
    <div id="x_axis"><img src="img/src/goes/here"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*NB: You can adjust the CSS height's and width's to suit your needs.*

Comment: I got it wrong. Please check this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706937/scrolling-using-jquery